# What is this ore, and why can't I mine it?

Tags: terraria

I just came across this glowy ore, and my 'Sharp Silver Pickaxe' won't mine it. I'm playing on the PC version of Terraria, if that helps.

How do I mine the glowy ore block?

[image: Terraria glowy ore]

Comment: Not sure exactly what type of ore that is, but there are plenty that are not minable without a higher level pickaxe: http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Ores  &  http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Pickaxe

Comment: *(looks at icon)* Been deputised lately?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I went into the chatroom to celebrate my first gold badge, and fredley kindly added another one to my collection. Also the old photo of me with a naked head was awful.

Comment: @shanodin Was it? I never looked close; it was distinctive though! Congrats on the Fanatic badge. (And now I should probably delete these as "too chatty"...)

Comment: Kinda amusing how a "What the hell is this?" question can be this informative for anyone who visits it. No sarcasm, it really is. Sure as hell helped me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking at [Demonite ore](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Demonite_Ore), which can be mined with a Gold pickaxe (or better).

Comment: Little patches of Demonite Ore show up deep in caves, especially when close to Corruption.  Best get started on that Gold Pickaxe!  (Also you really can't use the stuff until you get some Shadow Scales, so best prepare to fight Eye of Cthulhu and Eater of Worlds).

Comment: Ah, my confusion came because I mined it previously with my pickaxe because it was above ground (apparently above ground Demonite ore can be mined with any pickaxe)

Comment: @Zibbobz I...shadow...eye...worlds? I sense there's a lot that I missed out before I gave up last time I played this game.

Comment: Yes, Shanodin, there is.  Boss monsters for one.  And actually no, you can't mine Demonite at all with a silver pickaxe.  You may have mistaken a different kind of stone for Demonite Ore.  It...I don't think Demonite Ore even appears on the surface.

Comment: @Zibbobz it says on the Wiki page *"if the Demonite Ore is above ground level, it can be mined with any pickaxe."*

Comment: ...Consider my face red.  I honestly did not know that. Possibly because Demonite Ore that high up is so rare.