# What am I trying to mine, but can't, in Pre-Hardmode?

Tags: terraria

I'm Pre-Hardmode, Expert Large World, with an Iron Pickaxe, and Underground.

I spotted some sort of shiny rock in the dark, dug my way to it, and found that I can't seem to break it.

I hit it, and its image changes, but no breaking.

I looked up what materials need high levels of pickaxes to break them, but it doesn't seem to fit any of them, since it seems none of them should be Underground, Pre-Hardmode?

I haven't seen any lava yet, either.

No Screenshot, right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by shiny you mean glowing, it's either the [demonite](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Demonite_Ore) [image: demonite] or [crimtane](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimtane_Ore) [image: crimtane] ores. You will need at least a gold/platinum pickaxe to mine it, or you can also use bombs/dynamite (make them sticky with gel for more precise mining).

Outside of a handful of patches found in the corruption/crimson, it is so rarely found underground that you probably won't be able to craft anything meaningful with it. The best source is actually from the first couple of bosses you will fight. You will also need an ingredient only found by slaying a boss to combine with the ores to make the armor or pickaxe.

Comment: Oh... I don't think I've seen Corruption or Crimson. I thought they only appeared in Hardmode. Thanks!

Comment: @Malady if this answered your question you should mark it as accepted by clicking the tick next to upvote and downvote signs.

Comment: @Reflexive - Actually, voting to close as a dupe of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133769/what-is-this-ore-and-why-cant-i-mine-it